# Dynamically creating buttons with setOnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-button

I am dynamically creating buttons and I need to dynamically setting the `setOnClickListener()`  I am currently trying to use the below code but it gives me this syntax error:

```
private void AddButton(){
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(OnClick(this));

    layout.addView(delBtn);
}

public void OnClick(View v) {
    Log.d("Button", "Dynamically created button was clicked");
}
```

`"The method OnClick(View) in the type ActivityExample is not applicable for the arguments ()"`

How do I resolve this?

**EDIT:** I need to have the button on click listener method out of the `AddButton()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or this if you want to have a separate variable for the listener:

```
private void AddButton(){
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

    layout.addView(delBtn);
}

public OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Button", "Dynamically created button was clicked");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using annonymous inner class

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View V)
        {
              // do something
        }    
 });
```

Or make your class implement OnClickListener. Override onClick method and

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: I need to be able to do it using a separate method outside of the create button method sorry

Comment: @Nicholas make your class implement OnClickListener. then implemetn onClick method and then btn.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement the onClickListener in your class.